# infinite loop occurs when using array.splice inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, infinite-loop

I write this code, for inserting the second argument if any of the array items are bigger than it.
but suddenly an infinite loop occurs. ('result.splice(i, 0, num)' causes it)
Can anybody tell me why?!

```
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
  let result = arr.sort(function(a, b){return a - b})
  for(let i = 1; i <= result.length ; i++){
    result.splice(i, 0, num)
  }
  return result;
}

getIndexToIns([40, 60, 20, 0], 50);
```

Comment: Where is `arr`? What is `getIndexToIns()`?

Comment: sorry, I edited the code.

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: "if any of the array items are bigger than it" there is nothing in your code that does it. Basically you unconditionally insert new element in array making `i <= result.length` condition unreachable.

Comment: if you delete count is `0` in `splice` you are adding to the array instead of replacing. To make your code more maintainable create a new array instead of modifing the existing array. There is a rule of thump to never modify the array you are iterating

Answer (score 3):

Your

```
result.splice(i, 0, num)
```

inserts a new value at the index and increments the length of the array.

Beside that, you loop over the last given index, too.

Instead, you could sort and iterate from the end to replace grater values with the maximum wanted value.

```js
function sortAndReplaceGreaterValues([...array], number) {
    array.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    let i = array.length;
    while (i--) {
        if (array[i] < number) break;
        array[i] = number;
    }
    return array;
}

console.log(sortAndReplaceGreaterValues([40, 60, 20, 0], 50));
```